# Cannot resolve symbol 'Owin'

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm currently trying to implement an AspNet.Identity Authentication in an AngularJS Single Page App.
The weird thing is that in my ApplicationUserManager class , I want to use Microsoft.Owin and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin but in both cases I get a "cannot resolve symbol 'Owin'" error message.

Does anyone have an idea what is going on?
I have included the dependencies in my project.json and downloaded the packages. 
Simplified version of the ApplicationUserManager class is this:

```
using Matimez.Models;
using Matimez.Models.Users;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;  //Error message
using Microsoft.Owin;                  //Error message
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;


public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<NewUser>
{ 
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<NewUser> store)
    : base(store)
        {
        }

public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options, IOwinContext context)
{
    var appDbContext = context.Get<MyAppContext>();
    var appUserManager = new ApplicationUserManager(new UserStore<NewUser>(appDbContext));

    return appUserManager;
}
}
```

Here are the dependencies in my project.json as requested below:

```
  "dependencies": {
   "EntityFramework": "7.0.0-beta4",
   "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta4",
   "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta4",
   "MyApp.Models": "1.0.0-*",
   "MyApp.Services": "1.0.0-*",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.IIS": "1.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin": "5.2.2",
   "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.Owin": "3.0.1",
   "Microsoft.Owin.Security": "3.0.1",
   "Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies": "3.0.1",
   "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta4",
   "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin": "2.2.1"
```

*FYI I'm using VS Community 2015*

**UPDATE:**

So thanks to the advice of Behnaz, I installed the necessary packages and apparently that worked. Probably one of them was missing.

**However** the problem now are ambiguous references for the UserManager class which exists in both Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.

Even though I do not have a Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core dependency, Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin...has a reference to it, creating this weird loop. Also removing Microsoft.AspNet.Identity will not work as it is also referenced in Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: "I have included the dependencies" - please list them.

Comment: Added with an edit in the original post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to install some packages to be able to use "Owin":

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin 
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework 
Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 
Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin 
Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 
Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

From the Tools menu, select Library Package Manager and then click Package Manager Console, then install the packages by using the `Install-Package` command:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin
```

You can find more information in [Adding ASP.NET Identity to an Empty or Existing Web Forms Project](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/adding-aspnet-identity-to-an-empty-or-existing-web-forms-project).

Comment: Installing these packages worked,thanks. Apparently some one of them was missing.
However I am getting ambiguous references for example for IUserStore that can apparently be referenced both from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.

Comment: I think it is because of the versions of the libraries that you installed. As far as I know, classes are changed in different versions. So maybe you are using libraries which are not consistent with each other. I think, you'd better delete all libraries related to "Owin" and "Identity" and then install them again through packages.

Comment: It is very hard though to determine the right combination of versions. I'm still battling with the ambiguous reference issue, check this (new) question that I posted here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700074/ambiguous-reference-issue-microsoft-aspnet-identity-microsoft-aspnet-identity

Comment: Great answer.  I was trying to set up a blank ASP.NET Web API 2 project from scratch (I recommend first creating the ASP.NET Web API & MVC project as a reference point so you know what classes to create).  I had managed to create the required classes, install OWIN etc but it turned out I was missing a few things as per @BehnazYsfi post