# Ambiguous reference issue (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity & Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core

I'm building an AngularJS Single-Page App using the latest VS2015 Community and ASP.NET 5 etc...

The problem I'm now having while trying to implement an Authentication is that I need to use these two Namespaces:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity //Version 3.0.0-beta4
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin //Version 2.2.1
```

but since Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin has a dependency with

```
Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core
```

I keep getting ambiguous reference issues, for example for UserManager which exists in both Microsoft.AspNet.Identity and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core .

Has anyone else dealt with this before? 
Is it a version incompatibility issue or just the not complete Owin ASP.NET 5 implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` package is part of ASP.NET Identity 2, not the newest version shipped with ASP.NET 5. Trying to reference it will download ASP.NET Identity 2 and cause the weird error you're experiencing.

Just reference `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` and it should work.

Comment: Understood, however without reference to it, it seems that I can't use methods that I need, for example 
AppBuilderExtensions.CreatePerOwinContext 
(cannot resolve symbol error)

Comment: These extensions were specially made for OWIN/Katana to make managers' lifetime management a bit easier. With dependency injection directly integrated to ASP.NET 5, they are no longer necessary (and won't work with ASP.NET Identity 3 anyway).

Comment: Oh I see.. Hm although you answered my questions, you created many new ones hehe
Is there some reliable source of information for Identity 3 so that I can adapt to it? I was following some quides and tutorials which are obviously kind of obsolete in that way.. (Thank you by the way!)

Comment: You're welcome! The `IdentitySample.Mvc` sample you can find on github.com/aspnet/Identity is probably the best resource available right now: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/tree/dev/samples/IdentitySample.Mvc. If you're looking for something more complete, don't miss the `MusicStore` sample: https://github.com/aspnet/MusicStore/tree/master/src/MusicStore

Comment: Thanks again! I will give these a go. By the way the guide I was mostly following was this one here: http://bitoftech.net/2015/01/21/asp-net-identity-2-with-asp-net-web-api-2-accounts-management/ (Just so that I don't talk out of context)

Comment: Taiseer's tutorials are indeed pretty good. FYI, if you're trying to port the whole sample to ASP.NET 5, you'll probably realize that there's no authorization/authentication server middleware in this new world. You can take a look at this question for possible alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055477/oauth-authorization-service-in-asp-net-mvc-6