# ASP.NET v5 Multiple SigningCredentials

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NETv4 I used:

```
var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(keyByteArray);
```

But in v5 the last parameter of `new JwtSecurityToken()` is `SigningCredentials`, not `HmacSigningCredentials`.

So I try using:

```
var signingKey = new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials();
```

But that gives me the error `The type SigningCredentials exists in both System.IdentityModel.Tokens and System.IdentityModel`

How do I fix this?

These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "EntityFramework.SqlServer": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Abstractions": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-beta8",
    "Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Core": "1.4.0",
    "Microsoft.Owin.Security": "3.0.1",
    "System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt": "5.0.0-beta8-209291029",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin": "2.2.1"
},
```

From what I can tell, the conflict is between these dependencies:

```
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin": "2.2.1"
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-beta8"
```

If I remove the Entity Framework one, then I lose things like `public class User : IdentityUser`, if I remove the Owin one, then I lose things like `OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider`.

I seem to be stuck.

Answer (score 4):

The issue you're seeing is directly due to the fact you're referencing both ASP.NET Identity 2 and Identity 3 packages: Identity 2 references IdentityModel 4 (that comes with the full .NET framework) while the new stack uses IdentityModel 5. Sadly, both are incompatible and can't be referenced in the same project.
You can find more information here: [Ambiguous reference issue (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity & Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700074/ambiguous-reference-issue-microsoft-aspnet-identity-microsoft-aspnet-identity)

Remove your `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin`/`Microsoft.Owin.Security` references and it should work.

If you need an alternative to `OAuthAuthorizationServerMiddleware` that works with ASP.NET 5, you can take a look at this other SO question: [Configure the authorization server endpoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30768015/configure-the-authorization-server-endpoint/30788109)