# cannot convert from 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey' to 'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials'

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity, owin

While following tutorial
[Create a RESTful API with authentication using Web API and Jwt](http://www.developerhandbook.com/c-sharp/create-restful-api-authentication-using-web-api-jwt/) I'm having trouble getting the `CustomJwtFormat` class to compile:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataHandler.Encoder;
using Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace BooksAPI.Identity
{    
    public class CustomJwtFormat : ISecureDataFormat<AuthenticationTicket>
    {
        private static readonly byte[] _secret =              
             TextEncodings.Base64Url.Decode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["secret"]);
        private readonly string _issuer;

        public CustomJwtFormat(string issuer)
        {
            _issuer = issuer;
        }

        public string Protect(AuthenticationTicket data)
        {
            if (data == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(data));

            var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(_secret);
            var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
            var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(
               new JwtSecurityToken( _issuer, null, data.Identity.Claims,
                   issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingKey));
        }

        public AuthenticationTicket Unprotect(string protectedText) {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

The build error I'm getting is:

> Cannot convert from
>   'Thinktecture.IdentityModel.Tokens.HmacSigningCredentials' to
>   'Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials'

Having searched for this I found this SO post:

[ASP.NET v5 Multiple SigningCredentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33524030/asp-net-v5-multiple-signingcredentials)

I have tried the recommendation in the answer post but to no avail. I followed the link:

[Ambiguous reference issue (Microsoft.AspNet.Identity & Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31700074/ambiguous-reference-issue-microsoft-aspnet-identity-microsoft-aspnet-identity)

But am still seeing the conflict. Which package and namespace combination should I use?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I ran into the same problem.
You have to use an older version of System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt.

open nuget package manager console and run:

```
Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt -Version 4.0.2.206221351
```

Answer (score 35):

original method:

```
var signingKey = new HmacSigningCredentials(_secret);
```

new method:

```
var securityKey = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SymmetricSecurityKey(_secret);
var signingCredentials = new Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.SigningCredentials(
            securityKey,SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature);
        //---
var issued = data.Properties.IssuedUtc;
var expires = data.Properties.ExpiresUtc;
var token = new JwtSecurityToken(_issuer, audienceId, data.Identity.Claims, issued.Value.UtcDateTime, expires.Value.UtcDateTime, signingCredentials);
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'm using "voodoo chicken coding" here and you saved my bacon.